# Npm publish is failing with 400 Bad Request

Tags: npm, gitlab, npm-publish

I am trying to publish @babel/runtime package into my gitlab registry and while doing so i am facing E400 error. Adding the error logs below

```
npm notice === Tarball Details ===
npm notice name:          @babel/runtime
npm notice version:       7.18.9
npm notice package size:  30.2 kB
npm notice unpacked size: 202.4 kB
npm notice shasum:        dd63a562109741efdb37bd99af6873c143ea4f92
npm notice integrity:     sha512-V6s46s886z0JV[...]zG4PMb7qvVVSA==
npm notice total files:   193
npm notice
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://gitlab.server.net/api/v4/projects/69/packages/npm/@babel%2fruntime
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gitlab/.npm/_logs/2022-08-29T11_16_10_937Z-debug.log
```

adding the details of npmrc below

```
//gitlab.server.net/api/v4/projects/69/packages/npm/:_authToken={AUTH_TOKEN}
registry=https://gitlab.server.net/api/v4/projects/69/packages/npm/
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly you're violating the [package naming guidelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#package-naming-convention) - unless your group name is `@babel`.